# DevExpress Report Label FormatString not working for Date

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, date-formatting

I've been stuck trying to solve this problem few days ago with no result, so any help would be appreciated.

I retrieve date field from the database in the format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm) which I like to keep for sorting and other purposes, and I want to display the format in the XtraReport in the format (dd/mm/yyyy)

**Details:** 
I am developing a VB.Net project which includes DevExpress reports.  My problem with an XtraReport which includes a date field among its data, I am binding the report's labels to an empty DataTable in my project's DataSet,  and I fill the datatable and bind the report to datatable in runtime. Everything works great except that using the label's SmartTag to edit the FormatString property doesn't seem to have any effect to the output result.
*Please note that I don't want to change the source SQL Query format.*

Thanks,
Mohamed

Comment: The database **should** return the column as a date/time unless of course it is stored as a string. Do you know how it's stored?

Comment: Yes, Ciaran. The field is stored in a long date format. As mentioned in my question, I need to keep the retrieved SELECT statement untouched - which retrieves the field in the format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm). What I understand is that the label FormatString as supposed to be where I should manipulate. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Ciaran, I've submitted an answer, thanks to you, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was inspired from Ciarán commet:

> The database should return the column as a date/time unless of course
>   it is stored as a string. Do you know how it's stored?

The field type is Date/Time format. What I missd was that I use the FORMAT() method in the SELECT statement as following:

```
SELECT ID, FORMAT(SalDT,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm') AS InvoiceDates
```

Which indeed returns a String rather than the original DateTime format. I've changed the query to add a containing CDATE() and it worked:

```
SELECT ID, CDATE(FORMAT(SalDT,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm')) AS InvoiceDates
```

Since the returned format is now DateTime format, my XtraReport were able to apply the FormattingString dd/mm/yyyy which I've edited in the label's smart tag.

Thanks for help Ciarán and nempoBu4.

Mohamed

Comment: Okay, well that will work but you are taking a date or datetime column, converting it to NVarchar and then converting it back to date again. You would be better off simply using 'SELECT SalDT As InvoiceDates'. Also I'm a bit puzzled CDATE is a VB6 function, what database are you using that supports CDATE, - I ask purely out of curiosity.

Comment: As matter of fact I am following this conversion scenario in the INSERT and SELECT statements as the application is used in multi-culture machines, therefore the DateTime format is variant, and that way I am making sure everything is unified. Regarding CDATE, I am using MS Access database for my application - something stupid which I am willing to change in the upcoming releases.

Comment: Access is fine for some things. I use it extensively for quick reporting and queries against sql/server databases. It doesn't scale well however. Good luck with your endeavours.

Answer (score 0):

If your database return the column with values of `DateTime` type then you can use `Binding.Format` to set the format of values.
Here is example:

```
Dim dataTable As New DataTable("Data")
dataTable.Columns.Add("DateTime", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))

dataTable.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2003, 10, 5, 19, 12, 15))
dataTable.Rows.Add(New DateTime(1987, 1, 4, 11, 47, 53))
dataTable.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2010, 6, 25, 7, 25, 14))

Dim label As New XRLabel()
label.DataBindings.Add(New XRBinding("Text", Nothing, "DateTime", "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}"))

Dim detail As New DetailBand()
detail.Controls.Add(label)

Dim report As New XtraReport()
report.Bands.Add(detail)

report.DataSource = dataTable

Dim tool As New ReportPrintTool(report)
tool.ShowRibbonPreview()
```

If your database return the column with values of `String` type then you can use `CalculatedField` and `Substring` function in expression.
Here is example:

```
Dim dataTable As New DataTable("Data")
dataTable.Columns.Add("DateTimeString", Type.GetType("System.String"))

dataTable.Rows.Add("05/10/2003 19:12:15")
dataTable.Rows.Add("04/01/1987 11:47:53")
dataTable.Rows.Add("25/06/2010 07:25:14")

Dim calculatedField As New CalculatedField()
calculatedField.Name = "DateTime"
calculatedField.Expression = "Substring(DateTimeString,0,10)"

Dim label As New XRLabel()
label.DataBindings.Add(New XRBinding("Text", Nothing, "DateTime"))

Dim detail As New DetailBand()
detail.Controls.Add(label)

Dim report As New XtraReport()
report.Bands.Add(detail)

report.DataSource = dataTable

report.CalculatedFields.Add(calculatedField)

Dim tool As New ReportPrintTool(report)
tool.ShowRibbonPreview()
```

The result:
[image: The result]